# Laravel model Class not found, but i created the model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

When i execute my code that returns:

> Class 'app\Nota' not found

I try use `app\Notas::all();` instead `app\Nota::all();`, in the controller, but didn't work. I try too `use app\Notas;` instead `app\Nota;` but didn't worked for me.

My model:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nota extends Model
{
    //
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Nota;

class productoController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id){
        $notas = app\Nota::all();
        print_r($notas);
        die;
    }
}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: In your controller it should be `use App\Nota;` instead of `use app\Nota;`

Comment: `$notas = Nota::all();`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your controller code like -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Nota;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class productoController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id){
        $notas = Nota::all();
        dd($notas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$notas = Nota::all();
```

and replace `use app\Nota;` by `use App\Nota;`